# executing r script from Java: loading libraries

Tags: java, r

I want to use rgp to do a symbolic regression task. I am executing R script from Java using ScriptEngineEx. The R code works perfectly from Rsudio. However, just as I try loading the library rgp in java, I get an error message that "there is no package called 'rgp'".

First thing I tried was using lib.loc parameter for the library() function but got the same error message of not finding rgp.

Second thing I tried was loading  other libraries from the same directory as rgp (emoa (also did not work), and manipulate(was successful)). I can not understand why it worked for some packages and not for the others in the same directory

Here is my code:

```
import org.rosuda.jrs.ScriptEngineEx;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
```

`public class RScript {`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, ScriptException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
      ScriptEngineEx engine = (ScriptEngineEx) manager.getEngineByExtension("R");
    engine.eval("library(manipulate)");
    engine.eval("library(emoa)");
    engine.eval("library(rgp)");
    engine.eval("library(rgp, lib.loc =.libPaths())");
      engine.close();
}
```

The error message that I get:

```
Error in library(emoa) : there is no package called 'emoa'
Error in library(rgp) : there is no package called 'rgp'
Error in library(rgp, lib.loc = .libPaths()) :
there is no package called 'rgp'
```

PS: 
rgp, manipulate, and emoa are installed in directory:

```
C:\Users\userName\Documents\R\win-library\3.1
```

the value of .libpaths() is: 
[1] `"C:/Users/userName/Documents/R/win-library/3.1"`
[2] `"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/library"`

both stmts: `library(rgp)` and `library(rgp, lib.loc =.libPaths())` work fine from rStuido.
I hope you can direct me to further inspection to know why loading worked for some and not other libraries thought they are installed in the same location in .libPaths(). And any hint about how to load rgp would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to install them first. Like engine.eval("install.packages(\"emoa\", dependencies=TRUE)");

Comment: thanks for your respond. I have already installed them from rStudio and used them. Being so desperate, I tried: engine.eval("install.packages(rgp)"); from Java and got error: object 'rgp' not found

Comment: I haven't worked with R for a long time, but I remember that there should be quotation marks around package name. Try this install.packages("rgp").

Comment: you are absolutely right about that. The thing is I installed them from Rstudio before and have been using them there.. Never occurred to me that I need to install them again before loading. Now the packages are installed in the my eclipse workspace and the load stmt worked just fine.

Comment: I think it's because ScriptEngine and R have different libpaths (because r script engine shouldn't depend on your R installation). Finally, it's nice to hear that all work well now.